# How can I make parts of a menu context sensitive in Python?

Tags: scripting, python, interface

I am attempting to make a custom menu in Python that is context sensitive. Such that it's contents vary depending on which mode your currently in (e.g. Edit mode or Object mode).

However, when using an **if** and **elif** statement it doesn't work, and simply doesn't show those parts of the menu.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class QuickObjectOptions(bpy.types.Menu):
bl_idname = "object.display_options"
bl_label = "Quick Object Options"

mode = bpy.context.object.mode

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    if mode == 'OBJECT':
        layout.operator("object.shade_smooth", icon='SOLID')
        layout.operator("object.shade_flat", icon='MESH_UVSPHERE')
    elif mode == 'EDIT':
        layout.operator("mesh.faces_shade_smooth", icon='SOLID')
        layout.operator("mesh.faces_shade_flat", icon='MESH_UVSPHERE')
```

*Note: I've only pasted the relavant parts of the script above to keep it simple. The "import bpy" and register functions are definitely there ;)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question via **vitos1k** on IRC.

In order for the the if/elif statements to recognize the variable it needs to be placed inside the draw function.

Correct code:

```
class QuickObjectOptions(bpy.types.Menu):
bl_idname = "object.display_options"
bl_label = "Quick Object Options"

def draw(self, context):

    mode = context.object.mode
    layout = self.layout

    if mode == 'OBJECT':
        layout.operator("object.shade_smooth", icon='SOLID')
        layout.operator("object.shade_flat", icon='MESH_UVSPHERE')
    elif mode == 'EDIT':
        layout.operator("mesh.faces_shade_smooth", icon='SOLID')
        layout.operator("mesh.faces_shade_flat", icon='MESH_UVSPHERE')
```

Comment: Declaring a variable outside a function makes it a global variable. Therefore `mode` is initialized when the object is created but not updated when the value of 
`bpy.context.object.mode` changes.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. Thanks for the extra info @stacker

Comment: Note that this is even disallowed for addons, `bpy.context` is restricted to accessing only a few members. In this case its just annoying but if you store types that wrap internal data - you can cause crashes on further access if that data happens to be removed.

Comment: On that line ```mode = bpy.context.object.mode``` you can drop the bpy, because you already have context. so ```mode = context.object.mode```